# Combine frontend Thymeleaf with backend Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

How to call the backend API from front end which is thymleaf based when both the frontend and backend API are 2 different microservices.

And also I have a Eureka Server and microservices that are registered to this server. I have the frontend and backend APIs ready.

Can anyone help in how can I make the API call to the other microservice from the Thymeleaf templates html.

Following is the Architecture for my microservice:-

[Application Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scfR6.jpg)

Using Thymeleaf as frontend template.

Created the following modules:-

- web-ui module  : Thymeleaf
- service-registry : Eureka Server
- search-service & product-service : Spring Boot and
  EurekaDiscoveryClient

Need help in communication of web-ui with service-registry but not sure how to implement the api-gateway.

Comment: You need none kind of proxy, either local app controllers or an embedded proxy, like zuul. Eureka should not be available to the web app

Comment: Thank you. Do u have any repo or link as how to include the proxy?